# Chaining Arguments to a Function

Tags: java, android

I have often looked at API say the android api where you can add a pipe between arguments to combine them. Say *CENTER_VERTICAL|CENTER_HORIZONTAL*. How is this done ? Can anyone show me an example where i can pass multiple arguments to a function chained as above ? How do i read them ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertical bar is actually a bitwise OR, so the method only works when the arguments are "flags" or bit fields.

e.g.

```
private static final int FLAG1 = 0x01;
private static final int FLAG2 = 0x02;

callFunc(FLAG1|FLAG2); // (passes 0x03)
```

If the args are just "any old int", it probably wont do what you think:

e.g.

```
callFunc(0x03|0x01); // passes 0x03 - so the 0x01 does nothing.
```

Comment: Its actually bitwise OR, not logical OR. Logical OR would be ||

Comment: So if i have four possible flags that the user can combine in the application, how can i do this ?

Comment: @user365019 4 flags means you need 2 bits. Which gives you 00, 01, 10 and 11 as the possible outcomes.

Comment: 4 flags that can be on and off independantly need 4 bits: 0x01, 0x02, 0x04 and 0x08 would be the most common values, but any single bit binary value will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is something like what i wanted. Found the answer, so i thought i would answer my own question.

```
   public static final int a=1
   public static final int b=2;
   public static final int c=4;
   public static final int d=8;


    myfunction(a|b);

    myfunction(int x)
    {
       if((a&x)==a)
       {
          //Do whatever a stands for, and so on.
       }

      if((b&x)==b)
      { 
      }

      if((c&X)==c)
      {
      }

      if(d&x))==d)
      {
      }

    }




}
```